# R Shiny Application - Calculations Won't Render

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering if anyone can spot some errors in my code. My outputs have stopped loading. I think it has something to do with the ui.R file but can't seem to correct the issue.

here is my ui.R

```
library(shinyapps)
require(RCurl)
llama <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXlFu4HCza1C-0ENQzju5M332Y2pOmONqxS9CdQGyxg/export?&format=csv")
llama <- read.csv(textConnection(llama))
# pickType <- c(unique(as.character(llama$Pick.Type)))
# llama <- transform(llama, ChargeRate=TotalChargesWageIndexAdjusted/PatientCount)
# llama <- llama[order(llama$msdrg, llama$ChargeRate),]

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(
    list(HTML('<img src="ham.png">'),"wagers"),windowTitle="wagers"),
      column(3,wellPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("pick_type","select a pick type",c(unique(as.character(llama$pick_type))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$pick_type)))))),
      column(3,wellPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("result","select a pick type",c(unique(as.character(llama$result))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$result)))))),
      column(3,wellPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("sport","select a sport",c(unique(as.character(llama$event_type))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$event_type)))))),
      column(3,wellPanel
      (checkboxGroupInput("term","select an event type",c(unique(as.character(llama$event_term))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$event_term)))))),
      submitButton("Run Data!"),
   verticalLayout(mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                  tabPanel("Summary",
                  p("money in play for outstanding bets:"),textOutput("money_in_play"),
                  p("potential gain for outstanding bets:"),textOutput("outstanding_gain")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Earnings Report",
                  p("net gain or loss:"),textOutput("net_earnings"),
                  plotOutput("earn_sport")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Win % Report",
                  p("your win percentage is:"),textOutput("win_pct")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Pick History Report",plotOutput("earn_sport")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Explore Table",dataTableOutput("stuffOut")),
                  tabPanel("Help & Downloads",
                  p(textOutput("contactr")),downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
                  )
      )
))))
```

and my server.R

```
library(shinyapps)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
require(RCurl)
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
llama <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXlFu4HCza1C-0ENQzju5M332Y2pOmONqxS9CdQGyxg/export?&format=csv")
llama <- read.csv(textConnection(llama))
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  target <- reactive({
    llama <- llama[llama$pick_type%in%input$pick_type,]
    llama <- llama[llama$result%in%input$result,]
    llama <- llama[llama$event_type%in%input$sport,]
    llama <- llama[llama$event_term%in%input$term,]
  })
  output$net_earnings <- renderText({
    g <- sum(target()$net_gain,na.rm=TRUE)
    wcount <- sum(target()$result=="W",na.rm=TRUE)
    lcount <- sum(target()$result=="L",na.rm=TRUE)
    pcount <- sum(target()$result=="P",na.rm=TRUE)
    totalplay <- sum(wcount,lcount,pcount)
    pendingplay <- sum(target()$result=="")
    winP <- wcount/totalplay
    paste("$",round(g,2),sep="")
  })
  output$money_in_play <- renderText({
    a <- subset(target(),result=='')
    b <- sum(as.numeric(a$risk))
    paste("$",round(b,2),sep="")
  })
  output$outstanding_gain <- renderText({
    a <- subset(target(),result=='')
    b <- sum(as.numeric(a$to_win))
    paste("$",round(b,2),sep="")
  })
  output$win_pct <- renderText({
    wcount <- sum(target()$result=="W",na.rm=TRUE)
    lcount <- sum(target()$result=="L",na.rm=TRUE)
    pcount <- sum(target()$result=="P",na.rm=TRUE)
    totalplay <- sum(wcount,lcount,pcount)
    pendingplay <- sum(target()$result=="")
    winP <- wcount/totalplay
    paste(round(100*winP, 2), "%", sep="")
  })
  output$stuffOut <- renderDataTable({
    target()
  })
  output$contactr <- renderText({
    paste("For assistance with this data please contact support@hamsandwich.org")
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste("download", '.csv', sep='') 
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(target(), file)
    }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems were:

1. SSL
2. Redundancy in your import of the data between `ui.R` and `server.R`

**ui.R**

```
    library(shinyapps)
    require(RCurl)
    #llama <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXlFu4HCza1C-0ENQzju5M332Y2pOmONqxS9CdQGyxg/export?&format=csv")
    #llama <- read.csv(textConnection(llama))
    # pickType <- c(unique(as.character(llama$Pick.Type)))
    # llama <- transform(llama, ChargeRate=TotalChargesWageIndexAdjusted/PatientCount)
    # llama <- llama[order(llama$msdrg, llama$ChargeRate),]

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    list(HTML('<img src="ham.png">'),"wagers"),windowTitle="wagers"),
  column(3,wellPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("pick_type","select a pick type",c(unique(as.character(llama$pick_type))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$pick_type)))))),
  column(3,wellPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("result","select a pick type",c(unique(as.character(llama$result))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$result)))))),
  column(3,wellPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("sport","select a sport",c(unique(as.character(llama$event_type))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$event_type)))))),
  column(3,wellPanel
         (checkboxGroupInput("term","select an event type",c(unique(as.character(llama$event_term))),selected=c(unique(as.character(llama$event_term)))))),
  submitButton("Run Data!"),
  verticalLayout(mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                tabPanel("Summary",
                         p("money in play for outstanding bets:"),textOutput("money_in_play"),
                         p("potential gain for outstanding bets:"),textOutput("outstanding_gain")
                ),
                tabPanel("Earnings Report",
                         p("net gain or loss:"),textOutput("net_earnings"),
                         plotOutput("earn_sport")
                ),
                tabPanel("Win % Report",
                         p("your win percentage is:"),textOutput("win_pct")
                ),
                tabPanel("Pick History Report",plotOutput("earn_sport")
                ),
                tabPanel("Explore Table",dataTableOutput("stuffOut")),
                tabPanel("Help & Downloads",
                         p(textOutput("contactr")),downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
                )
    )
  ))))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shinyapps)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
require(RCurl)
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
dali <- read.csv("formdata_wager_entry - Form Responses 1.csv")
#llama <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXlFu4HCza1C-0ENQzju5M332Y2pOmONqxS9CdQGyxg/export?&format=csv")
llama <- dali
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  target <- reactive({
    llama <- llama[llama$pick_type%in%input$pick_type,]
    llama <- llama[llama$result%in%input$result,]
    llama <- llama[llama$event_type%in%input$sport,]
    llama <- llama[llama$event_term%in%input$term,]
  })
  output$net_earnings <- renderText({
    g <- sum(target()$net_gain,na.rm=TRUE)
    wcount <- sum(target()$result=="W",na.rm=TRUE)
    lcount <- sum(target()$result=="L",na.rm=TRUE)
    pcount <- sum(target()$result=="P",na.rm=TRUE)
    totalplay <- sum(wcount,lcount,pcount)
    pendingplay <- sum(target()$result=="")
    winP <- wcount/totalplay
    paste("$",round(g,2),sep="")
  })
  output$money_in_play <- renderText({
    a <- subset(target(),result=='')
    b <- sum(as.numeric(a$risk))
    paste("$",round(b,2),sep="")
  })
  output$outstanding_gain <- renderText({
    a <- subset(target(),result=='')
    b <- sum(as.numeric(a$to_win))
    paste("$",round(b,2),sep="")
  })
  output$win_pct <- renderText({
    wcount <- sum(target()$result=="W",na.rm=TRUE)
    lcount <- sum(target()$result=="L",na.rm=TRUE)
    pcount <- sum(target()$result=="P",na.rm=TRUE)
    totalplay <- sum(wcount,lcount,pcount)
    pendingplay <- sum(target()$result=="")
    winP <- wcount/totalplay
    paste(round(100*winP, 2), "%", sep="")
  })
  output$stuffOut <- renderDataTable({
    target()
  })
  output$contactr <- renderText({
    paste("For assistance with this data please contact support@hamsandwich.org")
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste("download", '.csv', sep='') 
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(target(), file)
    }
  )
})
```

Note that I downloaded the .csv to the working directory. Alternately, you could either import the file from the Internet but avoid using SSL or import the certificate and set up the SSL connection.